# Webmatrix helper : webimage can not upload image file

Tags: file-upload, webmatrix

I just start to learn the webmatrix, and installed the helpers library 1.1. the webgrid and chart are all normal to use .but when use webimage to upload a image file. it can not work. the code is :

```
@{  
  WebImage photo = null;
  var newFileName = "";
  var imagePath = "";

  if(IsPost){
      photo = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
      if(photo != null){
          newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" +
             Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);
          imagePath = @"images\" + newFileName;

          photo.Save(@"~\" + imagePath);
      }
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Image Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <fieldset>
        <legend> Upload Image </legend>
        <label for="Image">Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="Image" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <h1>Uploaded Image</h1>
    @if(imagePath != ""){
       <div class="result">
       <img src="@imagePath" alt="image" />
       </div>
    }
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "it can not work"? Do you get errors?

Answer (score 0):

This code example builds on the previous code example explained in the [Working with Images](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/9-working-with-images) chapter of the ASP.NET web site.

You need an "images" folder added to the root of your WebMatrix web application. You may also want to look at the [Working with Files](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/8-working-with-files) chapter. This chapter shows how to upload one or more files.

I hope this helps.

Erik